# Placing touch areas on an image that is drag, pinch zoom capable

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to place touchable hotspots on an image. The image (picture a desk phone with keypad, speaker button, hold, etc) is in a Framelayout wrapped within a RelativeLayout, and has a few buttons along the bottom. I need the image to be dragable, pinch/zoom-able, and have implemented that successfully following this article:
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=mantle_skin;content

I've tried a few ways to embed hotspots including this technique (from ip332):
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ffabb722efac62b2
that uses points to determine the hotspots. But with the drag & zoom feature, this obviously doesn't work because the points change whenever you drag or zoom. I could try to manually adjust all of my hotspot locations within the onTouch method whenever a motion is detected, but that seems a bit too hairy to me.

In a dream world, I'd like to somehow embed ImageButtons within the image and have the image and ImageButtons scale and move with the drag & zoom. ImageButtons would also allow the ability to give feedback (e.g. color change, etc) when a hotspot is pressed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `touch` events, save the touched location's x/y coordinates on `ACTION_DOWN` and compare those with the ones on `ACTION_UP`. If they're really close to each other and the time interval is less than X miliseconds, you have a click.

Comment: This it true, however it does not solve the problem. The x/y coordinates on any given touch may not map to the original hotspot because the image may have been dragged or zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by having my hotspots defined with XY coords, which I then translated based on the zoom and scale transformations of the parent image.  Using these transformed XY coords, I then painted a bitmap, and if the user touched within the XY area (+/- a boundary size), and didn't move their finger more than a certain threshold - then I took that as a 'click'

Make sense?

Comment: I intended my hotspots to be in the form of shapes (circles, rectangles). How would I transform those based on scale transformations? And when you "painted a bitmap", does this mean you painted the hotspots over the image displayed to the user? Finally, Android does not contain the java.awt package, which allows you to determine if a pont is within a shape (shape.contains(point)). How would you handle this on the Android platform?

Comment: Hmmm, rectangles would be simple enough (checking the X+width and Y+height), but circles trickier.  You could write a litte function to check if the touch area is within the circle with some basic maths (something like touchX > X+width/4 && touchY > Y+height/4...) ??  Probably a better sin/cos method but my maths isn't great in that area!

Comment: @ben_the_builder : May i request  you to put sample code if possible ..it will be great learning for me ..because I have also made custom relative layout and facing the problem of clickable area after the zoom